# How to access environment in datamapper migration

Tags: ruby, datamapper, database-migration

I have a padrino server application with `datamapper` as ORM layer. I have a database migration, say:

```
migrate 1, :test do
  up do
    execute 'Some Query'
  end
end
```

This migration is run using the command:

```
padrino rake dm:migrate -e <env>
```

Now my problem is that I need access to `env` in my query (not to choose schema or anything which datamapper does automatically, something very specific to the functionality). I tried debugging the migration to see if there is a variable which stores this value, but no luck. Is there a way?

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, since I am using `Padrino`, I can directly use Padrino.env inside `up do..end` or `down do..end` blocks:

```
migrate 1, :test do
  up do
    env = Padrino.env
    execute "Some Query #{env}"
  end
end
```

Although this is `Padrino` specific, but so is the concept of environment. I am sure something like this would work with other frameworks like `Rails` as well.